# Angle between chords in different circumferences.

Tags: geometry

This question is originally about the railroad. Consider the image at the bottom.

I want an equation that relates the angle $\alpha$ with the radii $R_1$, $R_2$ and the length of the segments $L$.

Note that one segment is a chord of the first circumference ($R_1$), while the other has its origin at the same circumference ($R_1$) but its end at the other one ($R_2$).

If both segments were chords of the same circumference, this would be an easy problem using the law of cosines. I did this, and got $L = 2 R \cos \frac{\alpha}{2}$ but I am not being able to solve this more complex case.

I would like the solution to be as general as possible, e.g. in the picture $R_1 < R_2$ but I am also interested in the case $R_1 \geq R_2$. Nevertheless, it will be also helpful if you provided a relation under certain restrictions for some of the parameters $R_1$, $R_2$, $L$, as well as other parameters that may be important here and I didn't take into account.

[image]

Comment: Do you have reasons to think that the equation $\alpha=f(L,R_1,R_2)$ you are looking for is independent of the place where you place the apex of the angle ?

Comment: no, not really... if that were the case I guess I could solve by parameterising the curve formed by joining the two circumferences like $\vec{\Gamma}(t)$ and the solution will depend on the position $\vec{\Gamma}(t_0)$ of the apex. Right?

Comment: As I understand the two line segments are waggon cars and you want to appreciate the distorsion occuring at a bend... You should indeed take a common parametrization for the two circular arcs,

Answer (score 1):

Data: two circumferences and the length $L$ of both chords.

$$R1: \;(x -c_{1x})^2 + (y-c_{1y})^2 = R_1^2$$
$$R2: \;(x -c_{2x})^2 + (y-c_{2y})^2 = R_2^2$$

Let's take a point in $R1$, $P(p_x,p_y)$

We can define a circumference centered at $P$ with radius $L$
$$R3: \;(x -p_x)^2 + (y-p_y)^2 = L^2$$

Now intersect $R3$ with $R1$ to get point $S1(s_{1x},s_{1y})$ and also intersect $R3$ with $R2$ to get point $S2(s_{2x},s_{2y})$

Be aware that circumference-circumference intersection has two solutions. You may choose the proper ones.

The angle $\alpha$ can be obtained by the dot-product of vectors $\vec{PS1}$ and $\vec{PS2}$

There are many quadratics formula here, so I doubt you can find an easy equation.